# Using universal-ctags, how do I tag a variable that references an entire file?

Tags: ctags

Using Universal Ctags, I'm trying to tag an Ember.js component so its name links back to where the component is defined.

The problem is that Ember uses the component's file name as the "definition".

As an example, in `template.hbs`:

```
{{#example-component}}
  Some text
{{/example-component}}
```

This component, `example-component`, would be defined at the path:

`/app/components/example-component.js`

That is the only place the variable name `example-component` is defined, unfortunately. It is not defined directly in the code anywhere else.

Ctags seems to handle traditional variable declaration just fine, as in `let example-component = {...}`. But I don't know how to tell ctags that Ember components are defined by their filename, not directly in the code.

Is there a way to write a ctags definition that looks at filenames for variables?

Answer (score 0):

I made a prototype for making tags defined by their filename in https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags/issues/1680. You can tell your requirement to me. To implement the feature you want, a pattern must be specified. A parser in ctags uses the patter for detecting that input js file is Ember.js component or not.